# Symfony2 command different behavior in cli and from incron

Tags: symfony, ffmpeg, incron

I'm using `incron` to watch a folder and each time a file is uploaded to it a Symfony2 command is executed to encode a video and store it in my application.

The encoding is made through shell scripts using `ffmpeg`. It works fine when I use the command in cli (php app/console ...) but when the same command is called from incron, it's like `ffmpeg` won't work.

Do you have any idea why the scripts would behave differently when the same command is used?

> shell_exec("/absolute/path/to/script.sh /absolute/path/to/file1.avi
>   /absolute/path/to/file2.avi /absolute/path/to/output/output.avi");

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, I had to put every single path used in the process in absolute. Hope this will be useful to someone else ! Thanks !